# Terminal License Purchasing

Tags: terminal

From where can I buy Terminal Server License? If Microsoft selling terminal license, please provide me the link for buy it. Actually we have 5 RDP users in our server system, we need to add more RDP users in server.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft licencing policy isn't straight forward, I would recommend contacting your nearest [Microsoft Partner](https://partner.microsoft.com/) and solve your licences with them.

Also look at these documents, [PUR](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/product-licensing.aspx) [EULA](http://www.microsoft.com/cs-cz/licensing/useterms/default.aspx), to find out which licences you need and which versions you can use with your product.

For example you may need to buy another CALs for your Windows Server along with your RDP Licence.